# How to trap when student is already log in or log out of the event, using Vb.net 2008

Tags: vb.net

This is my code for my button

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    user = 1
    If TextBox1.Text <> "" Then
        Dim namemo As String = ""
        ExecuteQuery("Select * from tbl_student where id='" & TextBox1.Text & "'")
        If reader.HasRows Then
            Try
                While reader.Read
                    namemo = reader.Item("lname") & ", " & reader.Item("fname") & " " & reader.Item("mi") & "."
                End While
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
            Call disconnectDB()

            'For Logging In
            If logStatus = 1 Then
                ExecuteQuery("Select * from tbl_log where studid='" & TextBox1.Text & "' and eventId=" & realid)
                If reader.HasRows Then
                    Call disconnectDB()
                    ExecuteQuery("Update tbl_log set  timein='" & Now.Hour & ":" & Now.Minute & "' where studID='" & TextBox1.Text & "' and eventID='" & realid & "'")
                    Call disconnectDB()
                Else
                    Call disconnectDB()
                    ExecuteQuery("Insert into tbl_log set studID='" & TextBox1.Text & "',eventID='" & realid & "', timeIN='" & Now.Hour & ":" & Now.Minute & "'")
                    Call disconnectDB()
                End If
                MsgBox("Hi " & StrConv(namemo, VbStrConv.Uppercase) & " You are successfully logIn", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Information")
                Call disconnectDB()

                'For Logging Out
            ElseIf logStatus = 2 Then
                ExecuteQuery("Select * from tbl_log where studid='" & TextBox1.Text & "' and eventId=" & realid)
                If reader.HasRows Then
                    Call disconnectDB()
                    ExecuteQuery("Update tbl_log set  timeOut='" & Now.Hour & ":" & Now.Minute & "' where studID='" & TextBox1.Text & "' and eventID='" & realid & "'")
                    Call disconnectDB()
                Else
                    Call disconnectDB()
                    ExecuteQuery("Insert into tbl_log set studID='" & TextBox1.Text & "',eventID='" & realid & "', timeout='" & Now.Hour & ":" & Now.Minute & "'")
                    Call disconnectDB()
                End If
                MsgBox("Hi " & StrConv(namemo, VbStrConv.Uppercase) & " You successfully logged out.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Information")
            End If
            TextBox1.Clear()
        Else
            MsgBox("Sorry " & TextBox1.Text & " ID number is not valid!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
        End If
        Call disconnectDB()
        '  TextBox1.Clear()
        TextBox1.Focus()
    End If
    user = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Clarify what you mean by 'trap' . And what do you want to happen when you do 'trap'

Comment: ohh sorry .im not good in english but i will try my best .if the student already login or log out . I want MsgBox to show that the user is already log in/log out because the user only login/logout once.

Comment: Example: The user is logging in. I want MessageBox to pop up that the user is already log in. Also same in Log out. He/she cannot login/logout twice.

Comment: If a student has logged out then they should have no access to the system to be able to log out again. Just a thought.